# Python: Finding the name of a enum class

Tags: python, class, enums

Given the following python code:

```
class Random_Skew_Enum( Enum ):
    NO_SKEW      = 0
    SKEW_LEFT_01 = 1
    SKEW_LEFT_02 = 2
    SKEW_LEFT_03 = 3
    SKEW_LEFT_04 = 4
    SKEW_LEFT_05 = 5
    SKEW_LEFT_06 = 6
    SKEW_RIGHT_01 = 7
    SKEW_RIGHT_02 = 8
    SKEW_RIGHT_03 = 9
    SKEW_RIGHT_04 = 10
    SKEW_RIGHT_05 = 11
    SKEW_RIGHT_06 = 12

    def _Convert ( self, enumeration ):

        text_to_enumeration = {}
        enumeration_name = ""

        def Do_Convert( self, value ):

            result = text_to_enumeration.get( value )
            if result is None:
                raise CCS_Enumeration_Error( "The enumeration '{0:s}' does not contain the value '{1:s}.".format( enumeration_name, value ) )
            return result

        enumeration_name = enumerate.name
        for enumerate in enumeration:
            match_data = self._split_enumeration.search( enumerate_name )
            new_key = match_data.group( 3 ).upper().strip()
            text_to_enumeration.update( dict( [ new_key, enumerate ] ))
        return Do_Convert
```

if I then code :

```
_Convert_Text_To_Random_Skew = self._Convert ( Random_Skew_Enum )
```

The line

```
enumeration_name = enumerate.name
```

generates an exception, I have tried other method to extract the name of the class from the parameter enumeration but with no effect, Can some one help?

Comment: `enumerate` is not `enumeration` (and it's a terrible name choice in general, since the built-in `enumerate` function has dibs on that name).

Comment: `Random_Skew_Enum['SKEW_LEFT_04'] is Random_Skew_Enum.SKEW_LEFT_04`

Answer (score 1):

The correct attribute to access the name of an object (*if it has one*) is `__name__`.

If you want the class name, you would need `type(enumerate).__name__` (or `enumerate.__class__.__name__` if you're using old-style classes).